# Why is a 3D marker symbol blacked out in the legend when saved to a .pdf file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, pdf

I must have been needing coffee at the time I posted that, but I am using ArcMap 10.8.1 and I was referring to 10.6 for the earlier episode.  Now, does anybody have any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Are you really using ArcMap 8.1?  I think that version was released around the year 2000.

Comment: Since there's no such thing as ArcMap 6.x (I'm sure OP doesn't mean ARC/INFO 6), I'd be fairly confident the question refers to 10.6.x and 10.8.1.